# Determine BMT or CMT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

Environment: Java EE 6

How to determine in Interceptor if the invoked bean is container managed (CMT) or bean managed (BMT)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beans are by definition always container managed.

Likely you want to know is current transaction CMT or BMT. Because [@AroundInvoke](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/AroundInvoke.html) interceptor method is executed in same transaction as intercepted business method, you can check transaction type with following:

```
public class SomeInterceptor {
    @Resource
    private javax.ejb.SessionContext sessionContext;

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        if (isCMT()) {

        }
        ...
    }

    private boolean isCMT() {
        try {
           //throws IllegalStateException if not BMT
           sessionContext.getUserTransaction();
           return false;
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
           return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course using exceptions to control flow is bad, but I am not aware of alternative method to differentiate between BMT and CMT.

Comment: It is, but likely there is no other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InvocationContext` to get `Class` and `Method` for which the interceptor was invoked. Then you can try to parse annotation for them and determine transaction management type. But this approach has one huge disadvantage: if transaction management property was set using `ejb-jar.xml` deployment descriptor then you can find no annotations at all or invalid overriden annotations. Also you can try to invoke `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> getContextData()` and discover result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like solving the problem at the wrong level. If tests like `isCMT()` are anyway not very object-oriented. Why not have two interceptors, one for beans with BMT and another for CMT? Use the right interceptor for the right beans... The two interceptors can still resuse common logic by inheriting a common parent class, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks but the whole point was to make it agnostic of BMT or CMT